# Websphere: Reset Profile when server will not start

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I was importing a profile from a 6.1 server using AdminTask when I apparently hosed my 8.5 server. I see the following...

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.ibm.ws.hamanager.runtime.config.CoreGroupLiveness.(CoreGroupLiveness.java:70)
>     at com.ibm.ws.hamanager.runtime.config.CoreGroupConfig.(CoreGroupConfig.java:117)
>       ... 39 more

Is there a way I can reset the profile to get my WAS working again? Does this mean I need to uninstall/reinstall?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackie,

There is no need to re-install the product if the profile is corrupted.

Was the import profile activity successful? Were there any errors during the import process? Look at the logs to see what happened during the import process.

You can create another profile and work with that.

If you had backed up your profile prior to the import, you could restore that profile using the backup else you will have no choice but to create another profile (using the PCT/PMT)

HTH

Comment: Mangu, I did export the profile to back it up first, however, the problem is the server doesn't start at all now so I can't get into the wsadmin tool to restore the profile. I think I deleted the log so I am not sure what happened in the import but it did fail, however, I tried to save and restart anyway to see if I could figure out what was wrong. So how do I create a new profile if the server doesn't start?

Comment: Restore config is typically done using restoreConfig.sh backupConfigFileName.zip. This does not need the server to be running.